# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database using java and JDBC code. I can't do that because I get the error below:

> java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the
>   following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of
>   service requested in connect descriptor

What is the reason for the error and how to fix it ?

PS- 
Out of all the DBMS, Oracle express 11g seems to be the most complicated and difficult to use.
Is that really the case ?

Comment: do you have same error when you try tnsping from console or commandprompt?

Comment: Use service Name instead of service id, for getting service name use "select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
>   descriptor

Self explainatory. You're requesting connection to a service or instance in a DB that the DB's listener does not know, so it says "I have no clue".

Check the way you installed your Oracle 11g express. Remember that the service name there is often "xe".

Comment: Yes. I changed the URL to "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" instead of jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl and something happened and then I got a new exception in my code. Will put it in a separate post.

Comment: Another issue is that when I create a new connection (say MyXe) and use the same in my URL, then my code generates errors.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand our issue. Please edit your question if it relates to the same error or open a new one. And please tell us what tool are you using!

Comment: i am using oracle SQL developer

Comment: Well, errors are marked for many reasons when you connect to a DB. Perhaps you missed a semicolon, it can even mark spelling mistakes so... without a particular block of code to check, your "other" issue is impossible to diagnose here. If the issue you asked is solved, please mark it as so or edit your question with the error that shows up now.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by increasing RAM size of my Virtual machine because i installed oracle
in VM that require more memory. So this could be one reason for your problem.

Comment: This means the instance actually did not (correctly) start